# Restructuring this JSON data to be tranformed to a barchart data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, bar-chart

```
    "Industries": [
        {
            "Country": null,
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Aviation",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Algeria",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Tourism/Hospitality",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "American Samoa",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Commercial/Retail",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Angola",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Agriculture",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Commercial/Retail",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Energy/Power Generation",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Telecommunication",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Antarctica",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Agriculture",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Waste Management",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Australia",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Beauty & Wellness",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Belgium",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Food & Beverages",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Belize",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Education and Training",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Benin",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Agriculture",
                    "Count": 39
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Beauty & Wellness",
                    "Count": 2
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Commercial/Retail",
                    "Count": 3
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Construction",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Consulting",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Education and Training",
                    "Count": 2
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Energy/Power Generation",
                    "Count": 3
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Fashion",
                    "Count": 4
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "FMCG",
                    "Count": 2
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Food & Beverages",
                    "Count": 6
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Healthcare",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "ICT",
                    "Count": 5
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Manufacturing",
                    "Count": 3
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Telecommunication",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Transportation",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Waste Management",
                    "Count": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this json data, how do i transform it to this

```
[
        {
            name: "Agriculture",
            data: [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,39]
        },
        {
            name: "Aviation",
            data: [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        },
        {
            name: "Beauty & Wellness",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2]
        },
        {
            name: "Commercial/Retail",
            data: [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,3]
        },
        {
            name: "Construction",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
        },
        {
            name: "Consulting",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
        },
        {
            name: "Education and Training",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2]
        },
        {
            name: "Energy/Power Generation",
            data: [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,3]
        },
        {
            name: "Fashion",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4]
        },
        {
            name: "FMCG",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2]
        },
        {
            name: "Food & Beverages",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6]
        },
        {
            name: "Healthcare",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
        },
        {
            name: "ICT",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5]
        },
        {
            name: "Manufacturing",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3]
        },
        {
            name: "Telecommunication",
            data: [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
        },
        {
            name: "Tourism/Hospitality",
            data: [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        },
        {
            name: "Transportation",
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
        }
        {
            name: "Waste Management",
            data: [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4]
        }
  ]
```

I have tried the following:

```
let countryData = data.Industries.map(country => country.Country)
document.write(JSON.stringify(countryData))
let industryData = data.Industries.map(industry => {
    return industry.Data.map(i => {
        return i.Industry
    })
})
let flatIndustry = industryData.flat(Infinity).sort()
let filterIndustry = flatIndustry.filter((a, b) => flatIndustry.indexOf(a) === b)
let getCount = data.Industries.map(industry => {
    return industry.Data.map((i, index) => {
        return i.Count
    })
})
```

Note: The result industry data will be sorted and will check each country if that particular industry exist, if not either append zero(0) or prepend(0) on the sorted industry value.
I am using this data in a stacked barchart

Comment: Please share the code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy `let countryData = data.Industries.map(country => country.Country)
   document.write(JSON.stringify(countryData))
   let industryData = data.Industries.map(industry => {
      return industry.Data.map(i => {
             return i.Industry
            })
      })
      let flatIndustry = industryData.flat(Infinity).sort()
      let filterIndustry = flatIndustry.filter((a, b) => flatIndustry.indexOf(a) === b)
   let getCount = data.Industries.map(industry => {
      return industry.Data.map((i, index) => { return i.Count
            })
      })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple javascript functions like `reduce` and `map` can be used to achieve the desired format. Checkout the demo below:

```js
const data = {
    "Industries": [
        {
            "Country": null,
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Aviation",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Algeria",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Tourism/Hospitality",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "American Samoa",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Commercial/Retail",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Angola",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Agriculture",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Commercial/Retail",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Energy/Power Generation",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Telecommunication",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Antarctica",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Agriculture",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Waste Management",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Australia",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Beauty & Wellness",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Belgium",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Food & Beverages",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Belize",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Education and Training",
                    "Count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Country": "Benin",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Industry": "Agriculture",
                    "Count": 39
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Beauty & Wellness",
                    "Count": 2
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Commercial/Retail",
                    "Count": 3
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Construction",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Consulting",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Education and Training",
                    "Count": 2
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Energy/Power Generation",
                    "Count": 3
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Fashion",
                    "Count": 4
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "FMCG",
                    "Count": 2
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Food & Beverages",
                    "Count": 6
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Healthcare",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "ICT",
                    "Count": 5
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Manufacturing",
                    "Count": 3
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Telecommunication",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Transportation",
                    "Count": 1
                },
                {
                    "Industry": "Waste Management",
                    "Count": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

const industries = data.Industries.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const industriesInCountry = cur.Data.map(x => x.Industry);
    acc.add(...industriesInCountry);
    return acc;
}, new Set());

const industriesCount = Object.values(data.Industries.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    industries.forEach(name => {
        if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(name)){
            acc[name] = { name: name, data: [] };
        }

        const countOfIndustryInCountry = cur.Data.find(x => x.Industry === name);
        acc[name].data.push(countOfIndustryInCountry === undefined ? 0 : countOfIndustryInCountry.Count);
    });

    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(industriesCount)
```

Comment: thanks. it worked but i would like it sorted. how do i do that?

Comment: Which part needs to be sorted? The values in `data` or the `industriesCount` array? Would this matter in the chart? @OlatunjiAbayomi

Comment: it doesn't matter though. Just thinking if the industry should be sorted but not necessary. Thanks @MaartenDev